# Bottom Sheet is not getting overlayed on bottom App bar

Tags: android

I have made an bottom app bar app with fab and bottom sheet and I have implemented the state expanded and state hidden from navigation on item selected listener.**The question is how to make bottom sheet overlay on bottom app bar the following result I have got is.**
***This is main activity xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_CoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFB7B7B7"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        android:elevation="26dp" 
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black" /> 
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="26dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_demo"
        />
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_drawer" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:elevation="16dp" 
        android:visibility="visible" 
        app:behavior_hideable="true" 
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"> 

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView 
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            app:menu="@menu/menu_demo" /> 
    </FrameLayout> 
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***Main activity class***

```
package com.bab.BottomAppBar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomAppBar bab;
BottomSheetBehavior<View> bsb;
CoordinatorLayout cl;
NavigationView nv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        nv=findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        cl=findViewById(R.id.activity_CoordinatorLayout);
        View bottomDrawer=cl.findViewById(R.id.bottom_drawer);
        bab=findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
        bsb=BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomDrawer);
        bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        bab.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_black);
        bab.replaceMenu(R.menu.menu_demo);
        bab.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1) {
                    bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);
                }

            
        });
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem p1) {
                    return false;
                }

            
        });
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

Result I got:

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZpam.jpg)

Result I wanted:
[See in this the frame layout as bottom sheet is overlaying on bottom app bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZMAH.jpg)

Someone please help me

Comment: Maybe because BottomAppBar's elevation is more than BottomSheet's?

Comment: yup i can see ok i need to check

Comment: can u please explain me elevation part i am confused in that part a littile bit

Comment: like  in instagram account you can explain me

Comment: check in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `BottomSheet`'s elevation more than `BottomAppBar`'s.

Elevation means how your views lay above each other